# Extracting digits from a cell with varying char length

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a group of cells, the first of the string never changes, it is and always will (until the coder changes it) `20` characters (inc spaces).

I then want to extract the 3 numbers (and in some cases 2) from the remaining sequence.

```
The monthly cost is 2 silver, 1 copper and 40 iron.
The monthly cost is 1 silver, 94 copper and 40 iron.
The monthly cost is 1 silver and 75 copper.
The monthly cost is 8 silver and 40 copper.
The monthly cost is 1 silver.
The monthly cost is 99 silver, 99 copper and 99 iron.
The monthly cost is 1 gold.
```

In the sample above you can see that there is no set value after the first 20 chars.

```
1 or 99 silver 
1 or 99 copper
0, 1 or 99 iron
```

I can't get a sequence that gets all the cells correct, I've tried the following:

```
=IF(J7<>1,(MID(TRIM(J7),FIND(" iron",TRIM(J7))-2,FIND(" iron",TRIM(J7))-FIND(" iron",TRIM(J7))+3)),"")    
results in:  #VALUE!  (when no iron)  

=TRIM(MID(J6,FIND(" silver",J6)-2,LEN(J6)-FIND(" silver",J6)-26))&TRIM(MID(J6,FIND(" copper",J6)-2,LEN(J6)-FIND(" copper",J6)-16))&TRIM(MID(J6,FIND(" iron",J6)-2,LEN(J6)-FIND(" iron",J6)-3))  
results in:  1 s9440   

=MID(J7,31,2-ISERR(MID(J7,21,1)+0))  
results in:  nd
```

If I `&` the cells as part of the calculation, they then don't calculate in the next mathematical step as I've had to allow for `spaces` in my code, in the case that there may be 2 digit numbers, not single.

```
=MID(J5,SEARCH(" silver",J5,1)-2,2)&MID(J5,SEARCH(" copper",J5,1)-2,2)&MID(J5,SEARCH(" iron",J5,1)-2,2)  
results:   2 140
not:       2140
```

What I need to end up with is:

```
2140  
19440  
175  
840  
1  
999999
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this lends itself to RegEx processing.  But that would require a VBA solution.  Is this of intereset?

Comment: @chrisneilsen most of my books are now being converted to VBA, so I'm always up for a new learning curve :)  Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to pattern matching in strings, RegEx if often the way to go.

In Excel, this requires a VBA solution, using a reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expresions 5.5"  (you can go late bound if you prefer)

Here's a starter for your case, as a UDF

Use it as a formula like `=GetValues(A1)` assuming 1st raw data is in `A1`.  Copy down for as many rows as required

This will extract up to 3 values from a string.

```
Function GetValues(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim re As RegExp
    Dim m As MatchCollection
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Set re = New RegExp

    re.Pattern = "(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)"
    If re.test(r.Value) Then
        Set m = re.Execute(r.Value)
    Else
        re.Pattern = "(\d+)\D+(\d+)"
        If re.test(r.Value) Then
            Set m = re.Execute(r.Value)
        Else
            re.Pattern = "(\d+)"
            If re.test(r.Value) Then
                Set m = re.Execute(r.Value)
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If m Is Nothing Then
        GetValues = vbNullString
    Else
        For i = 0 To m.Item(0).SubMatches.Count - 1
            v = v & m.Item(0).SubMatches(i)
        Next
        GetValues = v
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I've also tried using your code to break down each individual component, I've deleted from the `Else` to the respective `End if` but I get a blank cell.  I've renamed the function in this instance all the way thru to `GetSilver(Copper/Iron)`, and still the blank cell (#VALUE!).  I've tried to edit it a couple of different ways.  Is it possible to break it down?

Comment: RegEx is a powerful and flexible tool. You will need to adjust the pattern to match what you want.  There are many good free Regex design tools available.  The one I use is [expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

Answer (score 5):

This formula worked for me with your data, assuming text string in cell A1

`=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("silver",A1)-3,2)+0,"")&IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("copper",A1)-3,2)+0,"")&IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("iron",A1)-3,2)+0,"")`

I assume you don't want the value for "Gold"?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are just stripping digits you can use a short one-shot `RegExp` if you wanted the VBA route:

```
Function GetDigits(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "[^\d]+"
    .Global = True
    GetDigits = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method, using worksheet formulas, for returning all of the digits in a string.  Harlan Grove put it out there many years ago.

First define a Name (with Workbook scope):

Seq
Refers to:  =ROW(INDEX($1:$65536,1,1):INDEX($1:$65536,255,1))

Then, assuming your string is in A1, use the following **array-entered** formula.  (Formula is entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl+shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  (If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula.

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(1/(MID(A1,Seq,1)+1)),MID(A1,Seq,1)*10^MMULT(-(Seq<TRANSPOSE(Seq)),-ISNUMBER(1/(MID(A1,Seq,1)+1)))))
```

Comment: That formula is humbling.

Comment: @brettdj Harlan is a computer scientist; I think a professor/teacher; who used to contribute quite a bit to various Excel groups.  I learned a lot from him about Excel, and he motivated me to expand in other areas.  I haven't seen anything from him in years, though.

Comment: I think he did post at DicksBlog as *fzz* for some time? A remarkable mind.