# Remove characters A-Z from string

Tags: excel, vba

I need to be able to remove all alphabetical characters from a string, leaving just the numbers behind.

I don't need to worry about any other characters like `,.?@` and so on, just the letters of the alphabet a-z, regardless of case.

The closest I could get to a solution was the exact opposite, the below VBA is able to remove the numbers from a string.

```
Function removenumbers(ByVal input1 As String) As String
    Dim x
    Dim tmp As String
    tmp = input1
    For x = a To Z
    tmp = Replace(tmp, x, "")
Next
    removenumbers = tmp
End Function
```

Is there any modification I can make to remove the letters rather than numbers to the above, or am I going at this completely wrong.

The letters could fall anywhere in the string, and there is no pattern to the strings.

Failing this I will use CTRL + H to remove all letters one by one, but may need to repeat this again each week so UDF would be much quicker.

I'm using Office 365 on Excel 16

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? Maybe no need for VBA

Comment: if one has a subscription to office 365: `=CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)),MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),""))`

Comment: If "returning just the digits" is also an adequate description of what you want, then see [Extracting digits from a cell with varying character length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523745/extracting-digits-from-a-cell-with-varying-char-length) for both worksheet formula and VBA solutions.

Comment: Hey@RonRosenfeld thanks, the answers to that question got me close enough to come up with my own solution

Comment: I noticed that other solutions correctly ignore letters, but they only return numbers. If you also want to keep all special characters, you might want to try this formula: `=TEXTJOIN("",,IF((CODE(UPPER(MID($A$1,SEQUENCE(LEN($A$1)),1)))>=65)*(CODE(UPPER(MID($A$1,SEQUENCE(LEN($A$1)),1)))<=90),"",MID($A$1,SEQUENCE(LEN($A$1)),1)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
dim mystring as String
dim regex as new RegExp

Private Function rgclean(ByVal mystring As String) As String

'function that find and replace string if contains regex pattern
'returns str

    With regex

        .Global = True ' return all matches found in string
        .Pattern = "[A-Z]" ' add [A-Za-z] if you want lower case as well the regex pattern will pick all letters from A-Z and

    End With

    rgclean = regex.Replace(mystring, "") '.. and replaces everything else with ""

End Function
```

Try using regular expression.

Make sure you enable regular expression on: Tools > References > checkbox: "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5"

The function will remove anything from [A-Z], if you want to include lower case add [A-Za-z] into the regex.pattern values. ( .Pattern = "[A-Za-z]")

You just pass the string into the function, and the function will use regular expression to remove any words from in a string

Thanks